# Google Chrome - Problema de imagem em tela cheia

Tags: javascript, html

A imagem original é essa: http://4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/4k-image-tiger-jumping.jpg

Estou usando evento `click` para chamar função **"toggleFullscreen"**.

Segue o código:

**Html:**

```
<img id="image" width="450" height="350" src="http://4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/4k-image-tiger-jumping.jpg">
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#image").click(function() {
    toggleFullscreen(this);
  });

     function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
     elem = elem || document.documentElement;
     if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
       !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
       if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
         elem.requestFullscreen();
       } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
         elem.msRequestFullscreen();
       } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
         elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
       } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
         elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
       }
     } else {
       if (document.exitFullscreen) {
         document.exitFullscreen();
       } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
         document.msExitFullscreen();
       } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
         document.mozCancelFullScreen();
       } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
         document.webkitExitFullscreen();
       }
     }
   }

</script>
```

**Problema:** Depois de clicar na imagem, a imagem permanece o mesmo tamanho de tag img. Ela não está deixando a imagem original como essa: http://4k.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/4k-image-tiger-jumping.jpg em tela cheia.

Aqui está em jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j1fxt7ct/1/

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Pra mim ficou tela cheia :/

Comment: aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente, o jsfiddle deixou fullscreen sim.

Comment: Calma ai, vou tirar print e mandar pra voces

Comment: https://s27.postimg.org/emjmufspf/05_Dec_30_16_22.jpg

Comment: Ela deixou fullscreen sim, mais a imagem do tigre não

Comment: O problema é isso: width="450" height="350", está deixando a imagem pequena.

Comment: Testei e a imagem ficou `fullscreen`, não é alguma configuração do seu navegador? Abrir no `Firefox`

Comment: Eita porque o problema é google chrome ? O resto está ok

Comment: O tigre ficou fellscreen pra mim, estou usando firefox também @MatheusMiranda. Experimente testar com outro browser.

Comment: No Firefox funcionou sem problema.

Comment: Sim, @mauhumor, o problema está google chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o *google-chrome* coloque esse estilo para permitir full-screen:

```
img:-webkit-full-screen {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/j1fxt7ct/4/

Comment: Oi Lucas Costa, quase ! O problema continua, segue :https://jsfiddle.net/j1fxt7ct/3/

Comment: Ao abrir em tela cheia, ele está fixando height:350

Comment: https://s23.postimg.org/mlk1bblu3/06_Dec_30_16_40.jpg

Comment: Se vai preencher a tela toda ou não, depende das dimensões original da imagem.

Comment: Talvez tenha dado diferença devido ao formato da imagem. Atualizei a resposta @MatheusMiranda

Comment: Como que pode, um navegador mais popular, com problema da imagem kkkk